# Disable browser cache in PHP or JavaScript in a Flash application

Tags: php, javascript

We are developing a Flash site with PHP. the problem is that it storing the cache , but we have to disable the cache using JavaScript or PHP.

How can I disable caching?

Answer (score 24):

A common practice to disable browser caching is to set an expiration to a date in the past in the HTTP header.  Different browsers utilize HTTP header values differently so it is important to use many if not all of the following settings:

```
<?php
header("Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

Read more about [the `header` function on the PHP website](http://www.php.net/header).

Comment: In the PHP docs, they only mention the Cache-Control and Expires directives. Any official documentation on your solution? What are your references? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Try loading the movie with a query string, that should disable the cache. Note that the query string should be different every time.

```
<parm name='movie' value='movie.swf?ran=sfkjfsdkf23123'>
```

You could for example use php to create a random query string.

Comment: I usually append the time in this case.