# Viewing changes with WAMP and Chrome issue

Tags: google-chrome, wamp

So I'm using a WAMP server and Chrome to test a website I'm building and I often have an issue where I change the content of files and reload the page (even in a new window), and don't see the changes. Viewing the code in the debugger I still see the old code from before I saved out the changes.

My fix to this problem is that whenever it happens (which seems random) I have to clear my browser cache and restart the WAMP server, but this is a royal pain and I'm wondering if anyone knows a better solution (maybe some setting in Chrome or WAMP that I'm missing) to avoid this constant speed bump.

ANSWERS:

With jQuery (by Willy Wonka):

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache: false});
```

Without jQuery (by cowgod):

```
<?php
header("Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

[disabling the browser cache in php or using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404617/disabling-the-browser-cache-in-php-or-using-javascript)

Thanks Willy Wonka for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache: false});
```

Use jQuery to disable cache for your website.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way would be to use the debugger to disable the cache.

Press F12
Then click the Gear icon in the bottom right of the page
Select the General Tab under Settings
Check the box called Disable Cache