# How to disable cache in php

Tags: php, caching

I am using this code to disable cache in php but this code is not working on any browser. Please somebody help me, I don't want to save php web page in cache memory

```
header('cache-control: no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate'); 
header('pragma: no-cache'); 
header('expires: 0');
```

Comment: see [How to disable caching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/404617/disabling-the-browser-cache-in-php-or-using-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

```
header("Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT"); // *
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

- If the 0 in the header expires isn't working on expires due to old browsers not understanding it, you can try putting the date to a time in the past.