# PHP page not updating unless I press CTRL + F5

Tags: php

I have normal php project in which each and every page not updating unless I press CTRL+F5.

Now biggest issues is I can not press CTRL+F5 on logout.php where I destroy my session. Hence again I redirect it to login. Session is getting destroy and redirecting to login page but it'll not update unless I press CTRL+F5.

logout.php

```
   $_SESSION['user_type']       ='';
   $_SESSION['balance']         ='';
   unset($_SESSION['balance']);
   unset($_SESSION['user_type']);
   session_destroy();
   echo '<script>window.location.href="login.php"</script>';
   exit(0);
```

Comment: Why are you using a JS redirect instead of PHP's `header()` ??

Comment: If user has JS turned off, `<script>window.location.href="login.php"</script>` will just fail to redirect, consider using `header()` instead

Comment: Also, it seems like buffer issue, take a look at `ob_start()` and `ob_flush`

Comment: Mr. Shankar i tried using both JS AND header() it is redirecting but to login.php...and on login.php i'm print_r($_SESSION). this ll show session for 1st time and if i press CTRL+F5 it ll display blank array

Comment: had you start session in this page session_start();

Comment: Yes,Mr. Ganesh i have statement session_start();

Comment: I think it is cache. You need to disable HTML caching. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/404617/disabling-the-browser-cache-in-php-or-using-javascript

Comment: where should i put header("..."); line in php file??

Answer (score 1):

When you want to destroy a session you still need to place `session_start();` at the top of your page, otherwise session won't be destroyed correctly, also i would rather use `header();` to redirect to login page instead of `js`

```
header("location: login.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `echo '<script>window.location.href="login.php"</script>';` try using

```
header('location:login.php');
```

or

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=login.php">';
```

Comment: Mr. Ganesh..Thanx for reply...but i tried using both JS AND header() it is redirecting but to login.php...and on login.php i'm print_r($_SESSION). this ll show session for 1st time and if i press CTRL+F5 it ll display blank array

Comment: Echoing a `<meta>` refresh tag on its own is not good practice - this should be enclosed in a valid HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

Use `header('location:login.php');` to redirect you page after `session_destroy();`